# What are the common parts within the 2 and 4 stroke diesel engines?

Tags: engine, diesel

What are the common parts within the 2 and 4 stroke diesel engines.

- a) Piston, valves, cylinder, fuel injector
- b) Crankshaft, crosshead, cylinder
- c) Turbocharger, piston, gudgeonpin, cylinder
- d) Crankshaft, connecting rod, pistons
- e) Cylinder; connecting rod, pistons

I'm studying for an exam and there are some non logical answers.
Questions are especially for marine engines.
In the source the answer for this question is E.
But I think the answer is wrong.

If E is true D also must be true.
But if connecting rod is meant for an engine with crosshead (D and E are both wrong)
A wrong because of valves
B wrong because of crosshead

So I think the only answer should be c.

Can you help me with your opinions.
I want to send an email to the exam authority if this question is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This really does seem like a trick question. Is there any specific marine application which is being looked at? I mean, are they asking "basically" what is the same, or are they looking for specifics? If looking generally, C wouldn't be correct, because a 4-stroke diesel engine wouldn't require a turbo (a turbo isn't "required" but sure makes it run more efficient). I see what you mean, though, if looking generally, D or E could be correct ... strange answers. I guess they are looking for the "most correct" answer.

Comment: For E, a 2 stroke would have ports in the cylinder but a 4 stroke would not, so the "same" cylinder would not be a "common part"? That would leave D as the only correct answer IMO.